# Trying to modify data after a request in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

This is my first time trying to modify/stub a response in Cypress with bad data on a form that needs to be filled out in order to be created.

I am trying to do the following:

1. Fill out form
2. click submit button
3. intercept the call after the click action and change that response with no data
4. assert that the status should be 400 or assert that there was an error since no data went through

This is how I have the test written :

```
    cy.get("#name").type("John Doe");
    cy.get("#age").type("25");
    cy.get("#location").type("North Pole");
    cy.get("#save-button").click();
    cy.intercept("GET", "**/create-users/**", {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: {
          name: "",
          age: "",
          location: ""
        },
      }).as("newUser");
      cy.wait("@newUser").should("have.property", "error");
    });
```

When I run the test I think it is failing because the UI is showing that the form was created, therefore proving the assertion to be false and causing my test to fail.

Is there a way to do this?  I am trying to create an edge case where if something goes wrong such as no data went through after the form was filled out and submitted, the user should not be created.

Comment: What's the exact failure/error message? Can you validate that the intercept is actually being hit?

Comment: @agoff the error is the following: Time out retrying after 6000ms: expected {Obejct} to have error property.  I can validate it because when I check in console, it's yielding an empty object.

Answer (score 2):

The `cy.wait("@newUser")` passes an interception object down the chain as the `subject`.

If you look at the docs here [Using the yielded object](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Using-the-yielded-object)

```js
cy.wait('@someRoute').then((interception) => {
  // 'interception' is an object with properties
  // 'id', 'request' and 'response'
})
```

Since you are mocking the response, there's not a lot of point testing it's properties, but you may get some useful information from  the `request` portion.

```js
cy.wait('@newUser').then((interception) => {
  const bodySent = interception.request.body
  console.log(body)
})
```

If you want to check error messages on the `<form>`, this would be the code pattern:

```js
cy.wait("@newUser")
cy.get('form').should("have.property", "error")
```

Generally a form submit will not receive all the form fields back, usually it only receives the `id` of the newly created user.

You can check this by looking in `devtools/Network tab` during a normal form submit action (attached to the live server)

If so, the intercept would be:

```js
cy.intercept("GET", "**/create-users/**", {
  statusCode: 400,
  body: {
    id: '123'        // mocking the response
  }
})
.as("newUser")
```

If you want to mock the outgoing request instead of the response, use this pattern:
[Controlling the outbound request with req.continue()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Controlling-the-outbound-request-with-reqcontinue):

```js
cy.intercept("GET", "**/create-users/**", (req) => {
  req.body = {
    name: '',
    age: '',
    location: ''
  }
  req.continue()
})
.as("newUser")
```